# include ListView layout in activity_main.xml but how Activity class was called

Tags: android, listview

I want to include serval layout files in **activity_main.xml**

```
...
    <include layout="@layout/table_layout" />
    <include layout="@layout/relative_layout"/>
    <include layout="@layout/listview_layout"/>
...
```

The first two works good, but for **listview_layout.xml** shows nothing when run the application. Seem the reason is `ListViewActivity` class never be called(**ListViewActivity onCreate wasn't called**). So can't get datasource for listView.

**Question**:
How should i make the ListViewActivity class was called?

**listview_layout.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/blue"
        android:id="@+id/listview1">

    </ListView>
```

**ListViewActivity.java**

```
public class ListViewActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        ListView listview;
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.listview_layout);

        listview = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listview1);
        listview.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1,getData()));
    }

    private List<String> getData(){

        List<String> data = new ArrayList<String>();
        data.add("test1");
        data.add("test2");
        data.add("test3");
        data.add("test4");

        return data;
    }
}
```

**EDIT**:
The first two includes layout set properties:

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

EDIT:

if i put these code into MainActivity class it works, but if so my ListViewActivity seems useless. So is there a way to call the ListViewActivity in MainActivity?

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        listview = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listview1);
        listview.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1,getData()));

}


 private List<String> getData(){
   List<String> data = new ArrayList<String>();
            data.add("test1");
            data.add("test2");
            data.add("test3");
            data.add("test4");
   return data;
}

}
```

Comment: try changing your layout you passed to adapter. `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1`

Comment: Hi @DevendraSingh my list view part tested works well.

Answer (score 1):

Try to create an array adapter class with a custom listview layout where you can pass your listview array data size and the count.

Answer (score 1):

> want to include serval layout files in activity_main.xml
>
> ```
> <include layout="@layout/table_layout" />
> <include layout="@layout/relative_layout"/>
> <include layout="@layout/listview_layout"/>
> ```

Including the `listview_layout` has nothing to do with `ListViewActivity`, other than the fact it is also used there. You cannot nest activities inside of each other, so the only answer is to include the logic inside `MainActivity` as you have said.

An alternative to share logic would be to make `MainActivity` extend `ListViewActivity`, and add an overridable method in `ListViewActivity` to set the content view.

Something like this:

**ListViewActivity**

```
public class ListViewActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        ListView listview;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        createContentView();

        listview = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listview1);
        listview.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1,getData()));
    }

    protected void createContentView() {
        setContentView(R.layout.listview_layout);
    }

    private List<String> getData(){

        List<String> data = new ArrayList<String>();
        data.add("test1");
        data.add("test2");
        data.add("test3");
        data.add("test4");

        return data;
    }
}
```

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends ListViewActivity {

    @Override
    protected void createContentView() {
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your ListView may be hidden because other views height is set to match_parent/fill_parent and your ListView height is set to wrap_content.
Try changing the height of ListView layout, and then see the difference.

Comment: Hi @Umair, my list view activity wasn't called, so not datasource for list view. Not sure how to get the data.